# Next Image, image disappears with layout responsive

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to add the Next Image component to my project.

And I have a problem, the image disappears when I add `layout='responsive'`.

code:

```
<Box>
    <Link href='/' >
        <Image src='/images/logoDark.svg'
            alt='navbar-logo'
            width={260}
            height={56}
            layout='responsive'
        />
    </Link>
</Box>
```

Is there a solution? or any other way to optimize images?

Comment: Add the width 260 and height 56 on the container <a> inside of link

Answer (score 5):

Based on what is found here (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19314), it seems `layout='responsive'` has no intrinsic size. So you will have to add a width to the containing element.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the `next/image` into a container with `display:block`, so that the image will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

**set height and width for the parent of the Image component :**

```
<Box width={263} height={56}>
    <Link href='/' >
        <Image src='/images/logoDark.svg'
            alt='navbar-logo'
            width={260}
            height={56}
            layout='responsive'
        />
    </Link>
</Box>
```

ensure the parent element uses `display: block` in their stylesheet like `Box` component or `div`

Answer (score 1):

layout = responsive is no longer valid it is deprecated. This How used Image in Nextjs responsively

```
    <Box
        position={'relative'}
        width={526}
        height={526}
      >
        <Image
          src={Myimage}
          fill
          alt=''
        ></Image>
      </Box>
```

Make sure you wrap the Image with Box and give it a width and a height and also important to give the position={'relative'} if you are using 'fill' prop inside Image.

Image is Responsive like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Component**

```js
<div className="photo">
    <Image
    width={300}
    height={300}
    src="https:/images.unsplash.com/photo-1501432377862-3d0432b87a14?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80"
    alt="photo"
    layout="raw"
    />
</div>
<style jsx>{`
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .photo {
        margin: 0 auto;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        }
    }
`}</style>
```

**next.config.js**

```
experimental: {
 images: {
  layoutRaw: true,
 },
},
```

This worked for me, the image doesn't disappear and is responsive,